# Execute wasm code without JS

Tags: webassembly

I want to execute WASM binary file in the trusted(no access to HDD, etc) sandbox without JS parser or browser. Is it possible? Some examples pls? All example what I saw based on execution in the browser.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  this question doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline.

Answer (score 2):

WebAssembly is typically executed within a host environment (e.g. Browser, Node), however you can execute it within a stand-alone VM. Here are a few:

- https://github.com/AndrewScheidecker/WAVM
- https://github.com/LuisHsu/WasmVM

And here is a hardware solutions, a WebAssembly virtual machine in FPGA:

- https://github.com/piranna/wasmachine

However, all of the above are quite experimental.

Please note, that WebAssembly doesn't have any of it's own IO capabilities, so you might not be able to do much with any of the above!

Answer (score 0):

There is a new runtime which supports running wasm on any OS.

https://wasmer.io/